# Not Found http://localhost:3000/openapi.json -loopback 3

Tags: loopback

Please help me,I'm stuck at this point.

Steps done succesfully,
1)Install loopback 3
2)datasource is created ,generated models from mysql and generator script
3)updated model-config.json
4)loopback has run with no errors

Web server listening at: http://localhost:3000
Browse your REST API at http://localhost:3000/explorer
---This was command prompt
5)when trying to access that **Not Found http://localhost:3000/openapi.json**

[image: error]

Answer (score 0):

LoopBack 3 does not support OpenAPI v3, we support the older v2 specification only (it's usually referred to as Swagger).

The API spec in Swagger JSON format is available at the following URL:

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/explorer/swagger.json
```

Please check out the recently announced LoopBack 4 version if you are interested in OpenAPI v3: [the announcement](https://strongloop.com/strongblog/loopback-4-ga) and [the new website](http://v4.loopback.io).

Comment: tq for your quick response, but the solution i found was , i have uninstalled strongloop cli and left only with loopback cli alone and run the app ..it worked like a charm..

Answer (score 0):

I faced same error

Clear your browser cache then run URl

http://localhost:3000/explorer